# undefined variable localforage in angular2/typescript project

Tags: typescript, angular, localforage

I have a problem adding localForage to my angular2-seed project (uses typings and webpack). I'm new to typings and angular2.

With the typings commands, I added the Typescript definitions to `typings.json`

```
    "localforage": "registry:dt/localforage#0.0.0+20160316155526",
```

In my `vendor.ts` file I added

```
const localforage:LocalForage = require("localforage");
```

In my `service.ts`file my IDE can resolve the import and does auto-complete

```
import {localforage} from "localforage";

this.store = localforage.createInstance({
  name: "products"
})
```

but when I run the application, the imported localforage is `undefined`

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createInstance' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createInstance' of undefined
    at new SearchService (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:36:2), <anonymous>:20:53)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:189:2), <anonymous>:13:47)
    at Injector._instantiate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:777:27)
    at Injector._instantiateProvider (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:715:25)
    at Injector._new (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:704:21)
    at InjectorInlineStrategy.getObjByKeyId (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:247:33)
    at Injector._getByKeyDefault (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:921:37)
    at Injector._getByKey (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:867:25)
    at Injector._getByDependency (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:853:25)
    at Injector._instantiate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:141:2), <anonymous>:743:36)
```

Any suggestions?, thanks!

Comment: seems your angular2 app does't find out `localforage` in your service..ts file

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have forgot to instruct systemjs (as you are using angular2 I assume its your loader) what is localforage and where to load it from. Something like this should do the trick:

```
System.config({
 .....
  paths: {
    localforage: 'path/to/localforage/dist/localforage'
  }
 .....
});

System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I currently use `webpack` as loader. My project is based upon https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed

Answer (score 0):

Typings are only for compilation and not for runtime. So you need to configure SystemJS in your entry HTML file:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    localforage: '/path/to/localforage.js'
  },
  (...)
});
```

This way you will be able to import the localforage module:

```
import localforage from 'localforage';
```

Comment: I currently use `webpack` as loader. My project is based upon github.com/angular/angular2-seed

Answer (score 0):

Finally it wasn't a script loading issue, but I forgot to add the `export` keyword in `vendor.ts`

```
export const localforage:LocalForage = require("localforage");
```